# Is it possible to overwrite a file in java so it cannot be recoverd?

Tags: java, filesystems

I'm writing an encryption program that will encrypt files.

I want the encrypted content will replace the original content so it can't be recovered by recovery programs (That is, using the same memory addresses as the original content).

Assume that the encrypted content has equal size as the original content.

I guess that `File.renameTo()` will not do the trick since it's platform independent so it's somewhat unpredictable.

Forgive me for not posting my full code (duh!) but I use `Buffered Input/OutputStream` to read/write the data.

Comment: I have used the below link to have a base and change it as per my work place requirements. We do the same but with more fancy stuff as db driven keys, user supplied files. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-files-using-des.html

Comment: @user3509208 It's a nice piece of code, but it's not what I've asked. In your example, after erasing the orginal file, it can be easily recovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases (on some operating systems, on some filesystems, with some mount options) [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) will let you do what you want to do. Also think about how to keep sensitive data out of the Java heap... for example, avoid using `String` as part of the objects constructed from the unencrypted file, and later written to the encrypted file. However, in other cases what you're proposing is simply impossible. As stated in the manpage for GNU `shred`,

> CAUTION:  Note  that  shred relies on a very important assumption: that
>   the file system overwrites data in place.  This is the traditional  way
>   to  do  things, but many modern file system designs do not satisfy this
>   assumption.  The following are examples of file systems on which  shred
>   is not effective, or is not guaranteed to be effective in all file system modes:
>
> - log-structured or journaled file systems, such as those supplied with
>        AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFS, XFS, Ext3, etc.)
> - file  systems  that  write  redundant data and carry on even if some
>        writes fail, such as RAID-based file systems
> - file systems that make snapshots, such  as  Network  Appliance’s  NFS
>        server
> - file systems that cache in temporary locations, such as NFS version 3
>        clients
> - compressed file systems